# SQL Query using EXCEPT not getting completed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I am running a query like below,

```
select column1 from ABC
except
select column1 from XYZ
```

It has been running for hours and hours but still did not get completed. What is the issue?

The ABC table has 16,000 records, and XYZ has 5,000,000 records.

below is the actual query:

```
SELECT WFA1.ACTIVITYNM + '/' + WFA2.ACTIVITYNM AS "ACTIVITY_NAME"
 FROM  WFAACTIVITY WFA1, WFAACTIVITY WFA2
 WHERE WFA1.ACTIVITYNM IN (SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(WORKORDER)
  FROM TEMP_ACTIVITY_DETAILED_INBOUND
 WHERE WORKORDER IS NOT NULL
   AND PROCESS_FLAG = 'PROCESS' 
   AND STATUS = 'O'
  AND JOB_TYPE='Direct'
   ) 
   AND WFA1.WFAACTIVITYID = WFA2.PARENTID
   AND WFA1.ACTIVITYNM <> WFA2.ACTIVITYNM

EXCEPT

SELECT (UPPER(WORKORDER) + '/' + UPPER(OPERATION_NUMBER)) AS "ACTIVITY_NAME"             
  FROM TEMP_ACTIVITY_DETAILED_INBOUND
 WHERE PROCESS_FLAG = 'PROCESS'
   AND STATUS = 'O'  
  AND JOB_TYPE='Direct'
```

Comment: That is very general question... What does your statistics say? What indexes do you have?Table structure, data types etc....

Comment: Contention issues (locking or blocking) are most likely. Hardware issues are unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: What is the 'explain plan'? Probably, you have no indexes on column1 and the optimizer chose 'nested loops outer': so for each value from ABC it does full scan XYZ which results in 80 bln operations total. If XYZ can't be fully cached in RAM it's absolutely horrible. Your action depends upon DBMS you use - you may either exploit 'hash join semi' if any, or at least create an index on XYZ(column1).

Comment: there is an index available.

Comment: Ihave added the query as well...

Comment: I have added the query is as well and it have the index on the TEMP_ACTIVITY_DETAILED_INBOUND

Comment: Damn. DBMS version, explain plan, full schema. There are no prophets here.

Comment: Can you check with your DBA if there is any locking or blocking? Can you try with NOLOCK hint just to try once.

Answer (score 0):

You can phrase the query using `exists`:

```
select column1
from ABC a
where not exists (select 1 from XYZ x where a.column1 = x.column1);
```

For this to work successfully, you want an index on `XYZ(column1)`.  In fact, indexes might help your original query.

Other reasons why your query might be slow:

- The server is very busy.
- There are locks on the tables being used that prevent or seriously slow down read access.
- The tables are really views that are quite complicated.

Comment: I have added the query as well\\

Comment: I have added the query is as well and it have the index on the TEMP_ACTIVITY_DETAILED_INBOUND